# GWT - setProperty method doesn't effect on FireFox browser

Tags: html, css, firefox, gwt, browser

I have this code:

```
        colImage.getElement().getStyle().setProperty(isRtl ? "margin-right" : "margin-left", "41px");
        colImage.getElement().getStyle().setProperty(isRtl ? "margin-left" : "margin-right", "5px");
```

On Chrome browser it works fine and makes 41px and 5px margin accordingly.
But in FireFox browser it ignores these commands and doesn't put any of the `margin` properties.

And it hasn't finished yet.
I have the same commands work on another member, (called  `rowImage`). There, the FireFox browser makes margin-right of 41px, but doesn't make margin-left at all.

Can someone give me an explanation to this behaviour?
I had the same experience with

```
setProperty("pointer-events", "auto");
```

that FireFox completely ignores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to the JavaScript side of things, there is no CSS style property called `pointer-events`, nor even `margin-left`, `background-color`, etc. Instead, one must camel-case all of these properties to have them take effect as expected.

Try these instead:

```
colImage.getElement().getStyle().setProperty(isRtl ? "marginRight" : "marginLeft", "41px");
colImage.getElement().getStyle().setProperty(isRtl ? "marginLeft" : "marginRight", "5px");

...

setProperty("pointerEvents", "auto");
```

etc.

In fact, setProperty should be failing with the dash'd version of those style properties. From https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.java#2111

```
/**
 * Sets the value of a named property in the specified units.
 */
public final void setProperty(String name, double value, Unit unit) {
  assertCamelCase(name);
  setPropertyImpl(name, value + unit.getType());
}

...

/**
 * Assert that the specified property does not contain a hyphen.
 * 
 * @param name the property name
 */
private void assertCamelCase(String name) {
  assert !name.contains("-") : "The style name '" + name
      + "' should be in camelCase format";
}
```

Running in Dev Mode or Super Dev Mode would have run these assertions (or compiling with assertions enabled, though that can be a pain), and it would have failed when you tried to debug, with a constructive error message.

Comment: Thanks, you right. But I don't understand why in `FireBug` when I manually set style property `margin-left` it acts as I expected

Comment: When you use firebug, you are manipulating the css itself, not through a JS api. GWT is Java compiled to JS, so can only use the JS apis.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bad idea to use `getElement().getStyle().setProperty()` method. Try to define in your CSS `.is_rtl` and `.not_is_rtl` styles :

```
.is_rtl {    
  margin-left : 5px !important;
  margin-right : 41px !important; 
}
```

and

```
.not_is_rtl {
  margin-left : 41px !important;
  margin-right : 5px !important;  
}
```

Put in your code:

```
private static final String IS_RTL_STYLE = "is_rtl";
private static final String NOT_IS_RTL_STYLE = "not_is_rtl";
....
colImage.addStyleName(isRtl ? IS_RTL_STYLE : NOT_IS_RTL_STYLE);
```